# My categories help command is not working well

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make categories in my discord bot and I'm also trying to make categories help command, but It's not working well, so I need some help. Its not an error and there is nothing showing in my console of DiscordAPIErrors, Syntax Errors, or any error. It should display the chosen category and it’s commands in an embed message, but It’s not. It only display the specific commands help, for example, when I type (prefix)help kick it shows the kick command help, but when I type (prefix)help utility it only says that the command provided is invalid. So it only reacts with commands not categories. here's my code:

**Code**:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const fs = require('fs')
const { prefix, owner_id } = require('../../configs.json')

module.exports.run = async (message, args, client) => {
    const data = [];
    const allCategories = ['general','currency','premium','settings'];
    const categoryName = {
        "general": 'General Commands',
        "currency": 'Currency Commands',
        "settings": 'Settings Commands'
    }
    
    const user = await client.users.fetch('685079477629485093');
    const colors = [
        'WHITE','#add8e6','#e0ffff','#d3d3d3',
        '#20b2aa','#5d8aa8','#f0f8ff','#f2f3f4',
        '#b2beb5','#007fff','#f0ffff','#89cff0',
        '#a1caf1','#21abcd','#848482','#bcd4e6',
        '#f5f5dc','#318ce7','#ace5ee','#a2a2d0',
        '#6699cc','#0d98ba','#0095b6','#e3dac9',
        '#0070ff','#1dacd6','#08e8de','#e7feff'
    ]
    const randomColor = colors[Math.round(Math.random()*colors.length)];

    if (!args[0]) {
        let firstHelp = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor(randomColor)
        .setDescription(`
        Commands Usage: \`${prefix}(command)\`\nYou're asking for help, 
**${message.author.username}**? I'm here to help!
        `, { split: true })
        .addFields(
            { name: `⚙️ General`, value: `${(client.generalCommands.map(command => 
`\`${command.help.name}\``).join(', ')) || '\`coming soon...\`'}`, inline: true },
            { name: ` Currency`, value: `${(client.currencyCommands.map(command => 
`\`${command.help.name}\``).join(', ')) || '\`coming soon...\`'}`, inline: true },
        )
        .setFooter(`For more information about a specific command, ${prefix}help <command>`)
        .setThumbnail(`${message.guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true })}`)
        .setTitle(`E-Mod Command List`);

        if (!message.guild.iconURL()) {
            firstHelp.setThumbnail(`${client.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true })}`)
        }
        return message.channel.send(firstHelp)
    }

    const name = args[0].toLowerCase();
    const command = client.generalCommands.get(name)
        || client.generalCommands.find(cmd => cmd.help.aliases && cmd.help.aliases.includes(name))
        || client.currencyCommands.get(name)
        || client.currencyCommands.find(cmd => cmd.help.aliases && cmd.help.aliases.includes(name))
        || client.premiumCommands.get(name)
        || client.premiumCommands.find(cmd => cmd.help.aliases && cmd.help.aliases.includes(name))

    if (!command) {
        const categorySelected = allCategories.map(category => category.startsWith(name));
        if (name == categorySelected) {
            let { categoryCommands } = message.client.get(name + 'Commands')
            let categoryHelp = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor(randomColor)
            .addFields(
                { name: `${categoryName.map(category => category.startsWith(name))}`, value: 
`${(categoryCommands.map(command => `\`${command.help.name}\``).join(', ')) || '\`coming 
soon...\`'}`, inline: false },
            )
            .setFooter(`Premium commands can be used by specific users!`);
    
            return message.channel.send(categoryHelp);
        } else {
            return message.reply(`it seems you\'ve supplied an invalid command.\nPlease use 
\`${prefix}help\` to check out what commands do I support.`)
        }
    }

    let commandHelp = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor(randomColor)
    .addFields(
        { name: 'Description:', value: `${command.help.description}`, inline: false },
        { name: 'Triggers:', value: `${((command.help.aliases).join(', ')) || 'No triggers found'}`, 
inline: true },
        { name: 'Usage:', value: `\`${command.help.usage}\``, inline: true },
    )
    .setFooter(`Premium commands can be used by specific users!`)
    .setTitle(`Help | ${command.help.name}`);

    return message.channel.send(commandHelp);
}

module.exports.help = {
    name: 'help',
    description: 'Get a list of all commands or info about a specific command.',
    usage: `${prefix}help <command>`,
    aliases: ['commands', 'cmds'],
    cooldown: 3,
}
```

Comment: Speaking of it's not working well. Please provide more information, in what the result is now, any errors from log and expected result.

Comment: I’ve added more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can try making an array and make an object that you can push. If you use a command handler, it can be even easier to use.  Heres an Example with the command handler:

```
const roleColor =
      message.guild.me.displayHexColor === "#000000" ?
      "#ffffff" :
      message.guild.me.displayHexColor;

    if (!args[0]) {
      let categories = [];
//Use below for each category emoji, may pop up as Undefined
      const dirEmojis = {
        Category: '‍♂️'
      }
      const ignoredCategories = [`moderation`, `Other`, `suggest`, `Warn`, `Mute`, `ReactionRoles`, `Economy`, `Ticket`, `Welcome_Message`, `Welcome-Message`]
      fs.readdirSync("./commands/").forEach((dir) => {
        if (ignoredCategories.includes(dir)) return;

        const editedName = `${dirEmojis[dir]} ${dir.toUpperCase()}`;
        const commands = fs.readdirSync(`./commands/${dir}/`).filter((file) =>
          file.endsWith(".js")
        );
```

// If your handler does not use a folder for categories remove the dir, the dir is what the category name will be

```
        const cmds = commands.filter((command) => {
          let file = require(`../../commands/${dir}/${command}`);
          return !file.hidden;
        }).map((command) => {
          let file = require(`../../commands/${dir}/${command}`);

          if (!file.name) return "No command name.";

          let name = file.name.replace(".js", "");

          return `\`${name}\``;
        });

        let data = new Object();

        data = {
          name: editedName,
          value: cmds.length === 0 ? "In progress." : cmds.join(" "),
        };

        categories.push(data);
      });

      const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Here Are My Commands:")
        .addFields(categories)
        .setDescription(
          `Use \`${prefix}help\` followed by a command name to get more additional information on a command. For example: \`${prefix}help ban\`.`
        )
        .setFooter(
          `Requested by ${message.author.tag}`,
          message.author.displayAvatarURL({
            dynamic: true
          })
        )
        .setTimestamp()
        .setColor(roleColor);
      return message.channel.send(embed);
    } else {
      const command =
        client.commands.get(args[0].toLowerCase()) ||
        client.commands.find(
          (c) => c.aliases && c.aliases.includes(args[0].toLowerCase())
        );

      if (!command) {
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setTitle(`Invalid command! Use \`${prefix}help\` for all of my commands!`)
          .setColor("FF0000");
        return message.channel.send(embed);
      }

//This will show command info here

      const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Command Details:")
        .addField("PREFIX:", `\`${prefix}\``)
        .addField(
          "COMMAND:",
          command.name ? `\`${command.name}\`` : "No name for this command."
        )
        .addField(
          "ALIASES:",
          command.aliases ?
          `\`${command.aliases.join("` `")}\`` :
          "No aliases for this command."
        )
        .addField(
          "USAGE:",
          command.usage ?
          `\`${prefix}${command.name} ${command.usage}\`` :
          `\`${prefix}${command.name}\``
        )
        .addField(
          "DESCRIPTION:",
          command.description ?
          command.description :
          "No description for this command."
        )
        .setFooter(
          `Requested by ${message.author.tag}`,
          message.author.displayAvatarURL({
            dynamic: true
          })
        )
        .setTimestamp()
        .setColor(roleColor);
      return message.channel.send(embed);
    }
  }
}
```

This was inspired by reconlx, but modified. github.com/reconlx

If you decide not to use the handler method, do what is shown below:

```
let category = []

let data = new Object()

data = {
name: category name/ category array
value: commands in the category
}
category.push(data)

let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setTitle('Help')
.addFields(category)
```

Basic Command Handler Below (copy and paste into main file)

```
fs.readdirSync('./commands').forEach(dirs => {
        const commands = fs.readdirSync(`./commands/${dirs}`).filter(files => files.endsWith('.js'));

        for (const file of commands) {
            const command = require(`./commands/${dirs}/${file}`);
            console.log(`Loading command ${file}`);
            if (command.name) {
                client.commands.set(command.name.toLowerCase(), command);
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }
    });
```